# Download ContentNotes linked to entities by others

Tags: rest, contentdocument, contentnote

I have an org with SNotes enabled.
I am trying to use REST API to query SNotes on `Account`. If the current user adds an SNOTE, then a simple SOQL query like so returns it:

`GET /services/data/v42.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id,%20IsReadOnly%20FROM%20ContentNote`

However, if a note is added by ANOTHER user, the above does not return those.

Nevertheless, if i know the id, i CAN see it using:

`GET /services/data/v42.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id,%20IsReadOnly%20FROM%20ContentNote%20WHERE%20Id='0690SOMEIDHERE'`

I tried querying the notes using a subquery on ContentDocumentLink:

```
SELECT Id, IsReadOnly FROM ContentNote WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink 
  WHERE ContentDocument.IsArchived = false AND LinkedEntityId IN 
   (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Account.OwnerId = 'MyUser' 
   OR Account.Owner.ManagerId = 'MyUser'))
```

And, unsurprisingly, got back a

> Entity 'ContentDocumentLink' is not supported for semi join inner selects

error.

I can see the SNotes through ContentDocumentLink query like so:

```
SELECT Id, SystemModstamp, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.ContentAssetId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.Description, ContentDocument.FileExtension, ContentDocument.FileType, ContentDocument.ContentSize, ContentDocument.ContentModifiedDate, ContentDocument.OwnerId, ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocument.IsArchived = false AND LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Account.OwnerId = 'MyUser' OR Account.Owner.ManagerId = 'MyUser')
```

However, the results above do not indicate that the note is read only, so when i try to `PATCH` it, the query fails.

I need to know whether a group of notes are editable by a current user or not, through the REST API. Since there are potentially thousands of notes, i do not want to run the `by Id` selects from `ContentNote` for all of my notes, as the user will run out of API calls as limited by the org.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi  are you able to find solution for this..

Comment: @AnithaJJ sort of. I did what i mentioned in my post - i used `ContentDocumentLink` to pull out notes, and then on top of that i built an Apex rest endpoint which gives me back the `IsReadOnly`. This is all pretty limited but was the best i can do.